# Ul li dropdown select box

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, html-lists

I need a dropdown box using Ul li. I tried plugin: [tutorial](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CustomDropDownListStyling/index3.html)

The problem is that when I click on on of the li elements, the page is not redirecting.

Example:

```
<div id="dd" class="wrapper-dropdown-3" tabindex="1">
    <span>Transport</span>
    <ul class="dropdown">
        <li><a href="htttp://www.myweb.com/1"><i class="icon-envelope icon-large"></i>Classic mail</a></li>
        <li><a href="htttp://www.myweb.com/2"><i class="icon-truck icon-large"></i>UPS Delivery</a></li>
        <li><a href="htttp://www.myweb.com/1"><i class="icon-plane icon-large"></i>Private jet</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

But the link inside `<a=""...>` is not working, nothing happens, like in the demo.

Comment: there is a extra `t` in your `http`

Comment: sorry, i fixed link :)

Comment: then why don't you update your question?

Comment: My problem is not solved, i just corrected link to tutorial, where you can see example. I am not good in jquery, so i don't know why my links are not working :(

Comment: So you want it so when they select an item from the dropdown it redirects to that page instead?

Comment: You are absolutely right!

Comment: See my tutorial for a better way to use icons: http://preview.moveable.com/jm/ilovelists/

Answer (score 1):

According to this plugin, the magic happens here when you do the dropbox selection:

```
obj.opts.on('click',function(){
    var opt = $(this);
    obj.val = opt.text();
    obj.index = opt.index();
    obj.placeholder.text(obj.val);
    /* Below is the piece of code you want */
    window.location = obj.opts.find('a').prop('href');
});
```

[Here's a quick jsFiddle I put together](http://jsfiddle.net/mUbE6/) using their styles/scripts from the demo. I simply added that `window.location` snippet to the click function and voila.

Comment: Thanx a lot! it is working as it should. But now i have another problem. Basic thing, that i want that joomla language switcher have flags nearby language name. By default it was a simple dropdown with option. But i can't put flag images inside, so i decided to do a list and integrate plugin to convert it to dropdown. Now my problem is that after new language loads i can't see active language in switch box :(

Answer (score 0):

If you copied the source from the page, be sure to delete all of the javascript at the very bottom and very top of the page. This (somehow) fixed the **a** tag issue for me